# SQL placeholder using character versus numeric values

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, type-safety

I am trying to get more familiar with placeholders to to run SQL commands from python, but cannot successfully pass character commands. Here I describe a simplified solution that will be scaled up. In python I can create a basic SQL query using a placeholder

`sql = 'SELECT * FROM schema.my_table\nLIMIT %s'`

And set up to run the command wrapped in a function which takes the sql command plus a value (a limit to the number of rows).

```
def my_function(query, value):
conn=pg_engine().raw_connection()
with conn.cursor() as conn:
  cursor.execute(query, value)
conn.commit()
return rowcount
```

This can successfully run if I, for example, do `my_function(sql, [10])`, but if I try to run `my_function(sql, ['ALL'])` then I receive an error

> invalid input syntax for type bigint

So it is clearly expecting a numeric value; is there a different way of passing a character string in this instance, or another way of addressing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `%s` is for passing in parameters not SQL literals.  What Python library are you using for the Postgres connection? If `psycopg2` then look at the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for safe SQL string composition.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `psycopg2`, will take another look at the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

sql_str = sql.SQL('SELECT * FROM schema.my_table LIMIT {}').format(sql.SQL('ALL'))

print(sql_str.as_string(con))
SELECT * FROM schema.my_table LIMIT ALL
```

Though to be honest `sql.SQL` is not escaped.

You can get the same effect doing:

```
sql_str = sql.SQL('SELECT * FROM schema.my_table LIMIT {}').format(sql.Literal(None))

print(sql_str.as_string(con))
SELECT * FROM schema.my_table LIMIT NULL
```

This uses `sql.Literal` which is safer.